# merging pandas dataframes - getting NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, fips

I'm trying to merge pandas dataframes to effectively add a column with "FIPS Codes" according to the county and state in their respective columns.

I'm using pd.merge to do this and getting NaNs.  What am I doing wrong?

According to [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html](https://pandas.pydata.org) this should work.

```
merged = pd.merge(sales, fips, how='left', on=['county', 'state'])
```

Here is the head() of sales:
[image: sales.head()]

And here is the head() of fips:
[image: fips.head()]

And this is the merged result (with NaNs in the final fips column):
[image: merged.head()]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Standardise the state names across both dataframes. In sales, the state names are abbreviated, in fips the full name is used.